# C# Excel Chart with custom X-Axis

Tags: c#, excel, charts

i have a chart from two columns. In Column A are some result % values and in B i have the corresponding Name to the value.

```
A   B   
90  Test1   
82  Test2   
66  Test3
```

I want the A values as Y axis and already managed that, but i can´t get the names from B to the X-Axis labels.

```
Range chartRange;
Worksheet xlWorkSheet = (Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets[1];

ChartObjects xlCharts = (ChartObjects)xlWorkSheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
ChartObject myChart = (ChartObject)xlCharts.Add(10, 80, 300, 250);
Chart chartPage = myChart.Chart;

chartRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1:B"+movieCount.ToString(), Type.Missing);
chartPage.SetSourceData(chartRange, misValue);
chartPage.ChartType = XlChartType.xlColumnClustered;
```

Comment: EDIT: Funny thing: I got it working by swapping the values of the columns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to adapt to these settings, otherwise your xvalues will be just a count:

```
 chartPage.SetSourceData Range("A2:A4"), xlRows
 chartPage.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Range("B2:B4")
```

or

```
 chartPage.SetSourceData Range("A2:A4"), xlColumns
 chartPage.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Range("B2:B4")
```

maby there is a another way, but as a quick solution, this would work in VBA - so it should too, when you adapt it to your C# version.

Comment: I got it worked by swapping the column values, now i am gonna try to add another series